# Removing breadcrumbs from restructured text files in pycharm

Tags: python, regex, sed, pycharm, restructuredtext

I have about 13,000 files that I need to remove breadcrumbs from. The pattern at the beginning of every file looks roughly like this:

```
Title
=====

| |image0| `link <link1.html>`__ |image1| ::
  `link2 <link2.html>`__ ::
  `link3 <link3.html>`__
| **Introduced** : VersionXXX
```

In some files, however, the section between the title lines and the last line is either 2 or 4, depending on how deep the tree is. Regardless of the lines between the title lines and the final line shown here, I want that middle section removed completely. I can't quite figure out how to accomplish this and would appreciate some help. I'm using pycharm and they have a regex tool (which I have not had success with as yet), but I'm equally happy to use alternatives like sed or python to iterate through the files.

Expected outcome:

```
Title
=====

| **Introduced** : VersionXXX
```

Thanks for all the great solutions. **Final Solution** to avoid writing to a separate file:

```
import os

src_dir = '/PycharmProjects/docs/testfiles'
logf = open('failed_file_log.txt', 'w')

for filename in os.listdir(src_dir):
    print(filename)

    with open('{}/{}'.format(src_dir, filename), 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open('{}/{}'.format(src_dir, filename), 'w') as f:
        try:
            for i in range(3):
                f.write(lines[i])
            copy = False
            for line in lines:
                if copy:
                    f.write(line)
                elif line.startswith('| **Introduced**'):
                    copy = True
                    f.write(line)
        except Exception as e:
            logf.write('Failed to rewrite {}'.format(filename))
        finally:
            pass
```

Comment: could you share your exepcted output for above file

Comment: done. Thank you.

Comment: Is the title always underlined by at least 3 `=`, and does the first line you want to save always start with exactly `| **Introduced**`?

Comment: Line 2 always has an equivalent number of = to the characters in line 1. And yes, the final line always begins that way. (final line in this pattern, btw, not in the entire file.)

Comment: @Jason.  Understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for mostly fixed patterns, I would use Python without regex to copy the files. The process is quite simple: copy the first three lines, then skip everything until you get to `| **Introduced**`, and copy the rest over.

```
with open('myfile.rst') as fin, open('myfile_out.rst') as fout:
    for _ in range(3):
        fout.write(next(fin))
    copy = False
    for line in fin:
        if copy:
            fout.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('| **Introduced**'):
            copy = True
            fout.write(line)
```

Applying this snippet to a hierarchy of files and moving the output back to the input name is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This made the most sense for my application. Thank you kindly. I did alter slightly to avoid writing out a separate file (included at end of my question)

Comment: It's generally safer to completely write the output before you destroy the original.

Comment: fair enough, but in this case it's all in a git repo, so I can just revert the changes to my branch if anything fails.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As `sed` is tagged in the question by OP, following are the two one-liner to get the desired result:

```
sed -n  '/Title/{N;N;p}; /Introduced/{p}' input
Title
=====

| **Introduced** : VersionXXX
```

Or

`awk` :

```
awk '/Title/{print;getline;print;getline;print}/Introduced/{print}' input
Title
=====

| **Introduced** : VersionXXX
```

Comment: I stand corrected on the amount of effort in `sed` to solve this problem! Good show!

Answer (score 0):

This expression uses three capturing groups, and our undesired part is in the second one, which we can simply replace that (`$1$3`).

```
(.+\s*=====\s*)([\s\S]*)(\|\s+\*\*Introduced\*\* : .+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fHsKc0/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.+\s*=====\s*)([\s\S]*)(\|\s+\*\*Introduced\*\* : .+)"

test_str = ("Title\n"
    "=====\n\n"
    "| |image0| `link <link1.html>`__ |image1| ::\n"
    "  `link2 <link2.html>`__ ::\n"
    "  `link3 <link3.html>`__\n"
    "| **Introduced** : VersionXXX")

subst = "\\1\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: thank you! Will test shortly after my meeting. To be clear, the title itself is a pattern, and is a variable length depending on the page. the = line is always equivalent length to the title string.

Comment: thank you for this. I went with the simplicity of Mad Scientist's, but I appreciate the regex insight. Storing away for later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capturing groups and match what is in between by using a repeating pattern that checks if each line does not start with a pattern as the last line using a negative lookahead `(?!`

Then in the replacement use those 2 groups, in python using `re.sub` that replacement would be `r'\1\2'`.

```
(\bTitle\n=+\n)(?:\n(?!\| \*\*).*)*(\n\| \*\*Introduced\*\* : Version.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\bTitle\n=+\n)` Capturing group 1, match Title, newline, 1+ times a `+` and newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\n(?!\| \*\*).*` Match newline and assert what is directly on the right is not `| **` using a negative lookahead. Then match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(\n\| \*\*Introduced\*\* : Version.*)` Capture group 2, match newline and a pattern to match the last line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqiQ16/2)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` has it's uses, but it requires insane skills to do multi-line processing as you require. Here's an alternative in that tried and true *nix text processing language, `awk` ;-)

```
**cleanup.awk**
#!/bin/awk -f
{
  # print "dbg:$0="$0
}
/^$/{
  print $0
  inside_unneeded=1;
}
{
  if ($0 ~ /^\| \*\*Introduced\*\*/) {
    print $0
    inside_unneeded=0
  }
  else if (! inside_unneeded) {
    print $0
  }
```

You'll need to

```
chmod 755 cleanup.awk
```

and run it as

```
cleanup.awk file > file.new && /bin/rm file
```

If you can afford to keep backups (recommended), then do `&& mv file file.sav && mv file.new file`. OR you can redirect into a different directory  and then not have to deal with any `&&` processing, ie. `cleanup.awk file > /alt/path/for/new/data/file`.

will will produce the output

```
Title
=====

| **Introduced** : VersionXXX
```

There is probably a way to reduce the size of this script considerably using `awk` shorthand logic, but I leave it in a decipherable state for general public, familiar with `if/else if/else` type logic.

All blocks (code between `{ ... }`. are executed for each line of input, while the block beginning with `/^$/` is only processed for empty lines. If you have white space on those empty lines, you'll need `/^[ <tab>]*$/{` instead (and don't type `<tab>`, insert a plain `tab` char from the keyboard).

IHTH.

Comment: thank you for this, storing it away for future use.

Comment: Had to fix an incomplete variable name. Fixed now (I think ;-) ). Good luck.